# Beautiful Soup - Get all text, but preserve link html?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have to process a large archive of extremely messy HTML full of extraneous tables, spans and inline styles into markdown.

I am trying to use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to accomplish this task, and my goal is basically the output of the `get_text()` function, except to preserve anchor tags with the `href` intact.

As an example, I would like to convert:

```
<td>
    <font><span>Hello</span><span>World</span></font><br>
    <span>Foo Bar <span>Baz</span></span><br>
    <span>Example Link: <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #395c99;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;">Google</a></span>
</td>
```

Into:

```
Hello World
Foo Bar Baz
Example Link: <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
```

My thought process so far was to simply grab all the tags and unwrap them all if they aren't anchors, but this causes the text to be repeated several times as `soup.find_all(True)` returns recursively nested tags as individual elements:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example_html = '<td><font><span>Hello</span><span>World</span></font><br><span>Foo Bar <span>Baz</span></span><br><span>Example Link: <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #395c99;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;">Google</a></span></td>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(example_html, 'lxml')
tags = soup.find_all(True)

for tag in tags:
    if (tag.name == 'a'):
        print("<a href='{}'>{}</a>".format(tag['href'], tag.get_text()))
    else:
        print(tag.get_text())
```

Which returns multiple fragments/duplicates as the parser moves down the tree:

```
HelloWorldFoo Bar BazExample Link: Google
HelloWorldFoo Bar BazExample Link: Google
HelloWorldFoo Bar BazExample Link: Google
HelloWorld
Hello
World

Foo Bar Baz
Baz

Example Link: Google
<a href='https://google.com'>Google</a>
```

Comment: do you want to remove styles and other link attributes too?? because your input and output refers to that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the possible ways to tackle this problem would be to introduce some special handling for `a` elements when it comes to printing out a text of an element.

You can do it by overriding `_all_strings()` method and returning a string representation of an `a` descendant element and skip a navigable string inside an `a` element. Something along these lines:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, CData, Tag


class MyBeautifulSoup(BeautifulSoup):
    def _all_strings(self, strip=False, types=(NavigableString, CData)):
        for descendant in self.descendants:
            # return "a" string representation if we encounter it
            if isinstance(descendant, Tag) and descendant.name == 'a':
                yield str(descendant)

            # skip an inner text node inside "a"
            if isinstance(descendant, NavigableString) and descendant.parent.name == 'a':
                continue

            # default behavior
            if (
                (types is None and not isinstance(descendant, NavigableString))
                or
                (types is not None and type(descendant) not in types)):
                continue

            if strip:
                descendant = descendant.strip()
                if len(descendant) == 0:
                    continue
            yield descendant
```

Demo:

```
In [1]: data = """
   ...: <td>
   ...:     <font><span>Hello</span><span>World</span></font><br>
   ...:     <span>Foo Bar <span>Baz</span></span><br>
   ...:     <span>Example Link: <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #395c99;font-weight: normal;tex
   ...: t-decoration: underline;">Google</a></span>
   ...: </td>
   ...: """

In [2]: soup = MyBeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

In [3]: print(soup.get_text())

HelloWorld
Foo Bar Baz
Example Link: <a href="https://google.com" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #395c99;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you, this is a flexible, elegant solution that I never would have thought of. I made a small adjustment to the handling of the `a` tag to output as I wanted, and it's perfect.

Comment: How could it return only the href attribute? Like:
`Example Link: <https://google.com>`

Comment: Answering my own question, just change:
`if isinstance(descendant, Tag) and descendant.name == 'a':
                yield str(descendant)`
To:
`if isinstance(descendant, Tag) and descendant.name == 'a':
                yield str('<{}> '.format(descendant.get('href', '')))`

Comment: wonder if is version updated, I run the example code with error
File "/Users/xhuang9/pros/station1/t1.py", line 20, in _all_strings
    (types is not None and type(descendant) not in types)):
TypeError: argument of type 'object' is not iterable

Comment: I have same issue as @alextre. It will be great if someone can share an update.

Answer (score 2):

To only consider direct children set recursive = False then you need to process each 'td' and extract the text and anchor link individually.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example_html = '<td><font><span>Some Example Text</span></font><br><span>Another Example Text</span><br><span>Example Link: <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #395c99;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;">Google</a></span></td>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(example_html, 'lxml')
tags = soup.find_all(recursive=False)
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.text)
    print(tag.find('a'))
```

If you want the text printed on separate lines you will have to process the spans individually.

```
for tag in tags:
    spans = tag.find_all('span')
    for span in spans:
        print(span.text)
print(tag.find('a'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution accepted is not working for me (I had the same issue as @alextre, probably due to a version changes).
However, I managed to resolve it by making modifications and overriding the get_text() method instead of all_string().

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, CData, Tag
class MyBeautifulSoup(BeautifulSoup):
    def get_text(self, separator='', strip=False, types=(NavigableString,)):
        text_parts = []

        for element in self.descendants:
            if isinstance(element, NavigableString):
                text_parts.append(str(element))
            elif isinstance(element, Tag):
                if element.name == 'a' and 'href' in element.attrs:
                    text_parts.append(element.get_text(separator=separator, strip=strip))
                    text_parts.append('(' + element['href'] + ')')
                elif isinstance(element, types):
                    text_parts.append(element.get_text(separator=separator, strip=strip))

        return separator.join(text_parts)```
````

Comment: your last `elif` seems to be impossible to reach, because you already checked that it's of type `Tag` before entering the last if/elif block?