# Parse html to text and keep the links in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to parse a html into text, but need to keep the hyperlinks.
I'm using beautiful soap (bs4), but the get_text() gets only the text and ignores any hrefs.
Example:

```
<a href="http://example.com/">Example</a>
```

Parsed with bs4 is:

```
Example
```

I need it to be something like:

```
Example <http://example.com/>
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52026908) should cover your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the `href` attribute of the `a` tag (`a_tag['href']`) as well:

```
In [16]: text = '<a href="http://example.com/">Example</a>'

In [17]: soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')

In [18]: a_tag = soup.select_one('a')

In [19]: '{} <{}>'.format(a_tag.text, a_tag['href'])
Out[19]: 'Example <http://example.com/>'
```